Name of this type of graph?
What is the name of a graph that has $1$ central node connected to $n$ other nodes, each of them connected to $n-1$ distinct nodes, and so on?
At the end of the process the central node has degree $n$, as do all the other nodes apart from the last layer that have degree 1 (the leaves). I would like to know if this kind of graph has a specific name, and if there are known properties.
In this picture we see n=3 l=2 how it will appear a tree for n = 3 at the second layer, the zero layer is the root, the first layer are the 3 nodes connected (n) the second layer are the n-1 new nodes  connected with the parents node.
I hope it will help

I'm not sure I understand the description correctly, but this seems to be a complete $n$-ary tree without one of its subtrees

You could also describe it as a ball of a certain radius in the (unrooted) infinite $n$-ary tree.

I think I have seen such graphs but I am sure that I have never known any specific name for them. As Sam mentioned above, it seems very reasonable to call such graphs a "ball" of the given radius and centered at the central node (if there are multiple such components in a graph).

there is not a know name in the literature ?

The "ball" terminology is completely standard: in general the ball $B_r(x)$ of radius $r$ centered at a vertex $x$ in a graph is the subgraph of all vertices at distance less than or equal to $r$ from $x$. And so indeed the graph you are talking is the ball of given radius in the (infinite) $n$-regular tree graph (centered at any vertex).

Incidentally, the comment of @CommandMaster seems slightly off to me. I would say rather that this graph is a complete $(n-1)$-ary tree (which I take to mean a rooted tree), with one extra subtree connected to the root.

I've provided an image as example, hope will make the question more clear

The infinite version of this graph -- so continuing indefinitely, no layer of vertices of degree one -- is called the regular tree (or Bethe lattice) of  degree (or coordination number) $n$ in maths and statistical mechanics. It has its own wikipedia page. Inspired by the definition of 'perfect binary tree' on wikipedia a suggestion could be the regular tree (or Bethe lattice) of a given depth?
For related terminology see Wikipedia on Trees.

I would hesitate to call it regular if it is not actually regular. Again, what is wrong with "ball (of given radius) in the $n$-regular tree"?

I just wanted to add another term ('Bethe lattice') in case the OP is more stat-mech oriented. I have no objections to your suggestion to use "ball" (+1) @SamHopkins
